# Per installation configuration for SalesForce Application

Tags: salesforce

I want my SalesForce Application to behave differently depending on a value that's set per environment. The value can be one of two values at present and will result in a different page being loaded and a different object instance being updated by the page.

Where would be the best place to store this? A single instance of a custom object? Or is there a dedicated store for this? Ideally the value could be updated using the Api so that a we can updated it without having to get clients to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want to use a Custom Setting — these are similar to objects but setup exactly for this kind of thing, and they can even be done in a hierarchy such that different settings are used for different users.

[Help for custom settings is here](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/cs_about.htm) (must be logged in) and [reference docs are here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm).

Comment: List Custom Settings are the SFDC-recommended way to do this, and usually the most appropriate. I've also found that sometimes, depending on requirements, Custom Labels can be a fit; key differences are that they can be deployed via package.xml and they can be referred to via formulas. They also can return different config values based on user locale, which is occasionally useful.

Comment: Is it possible to add a custom settings instance when an app is installed or must this be manually set up?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this through code, so you could have a custom API call you use to do it or just use the standard API.